# Shell script conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008, shell

I am trying to get data from a text file using a shell script, by searching in some lines with more than one condition. For example in this file:

```
TX VIDEO ID 34 B 33 SIZE 672 SRC -1 DST 11 
TX CBR ID 35 B 35 SIZE 10 SRC -1 DST 11  
RX VOIP ID 0 B 0 SIZE 32 SRC -1 DST 3 D  
RX VOIP ID 8 B 8 SIZE 32 SRC -1 DST 5 D 
RX VOIP ID 20 B 20 SIZE 32 SRC -1 DST 8 D 
RX VIDEO ID 9 B 9 SIZE 1490 SRC -1 DST 5 D 
RX VIDEO ID 21 B 21 SIZE 1490 SRC -1 DST 8 D 
TX INF_BUF ID 37 B 10 SIZE 776 SRC 1 DST 5 T 
TX INF_BUF ID 39 B 22 SIZE 776 SRC 2 DST 8 T
```

I have both the `"RX VIDEO"` and `"TX VIDEO"` lines. The first condition is, take data from all the `"RX VIDEO"` within the `"DST 3 && DST 5"`.

Answer (score 1):

For more than one condition you can pipe greps output to another grep.

If you want to search a file for lines with AAA and BBB you can do:

```
grep 'AAA' file | grep 'BBB'
```

Or you can search it with regular expressions with only one grep:

```
grep -e 'AAA.*BBB' -e 'BBB.*AAA' file
```

If an expressions after any of the `-e` options are matched, you will get a result. That means that it acts like *or*.

Both examples will find lines like this ones:

```
AAABBB
AAA BBB
BBB AAA
BBBAAA
AAA-BBB
AAA---BBB
AAAA BBB
xAAAAAAA BBB AAAAA
```

and so on.

**For your example it could be:**

```
grep 'RX VIDEO' file | grep -e 'DST 3\>' -e 'DST 5\>'
```

Or:

```
grep 'RX VIDEO.*DST [35]\>' file
```

This will search for `RX VIDEO` together with `DST 3` or `DST 5`.

Edit: I added a word ending at the end of the expressions to surpress for example DST 37 beeing found. See Keith’s comment.

Comment: Note that grepping for `'DST 3'` will also match `DST 37`. You might want to specify word boundaries: `grep 'RX VIDEO.*DST [35]\>' file`